# I seem to have two different accounts here; how do I merge them?

Tags: support, openid

I've joined a few other SE sites and my original identity migrated just fine.  Here I can log in with either of my two openID accounts but it's not the same account -- contrast with my account on judaism.stackexchange.com, which knows about both openIDs.  I'm not sure how I ended up with different identities (with different histories and reputations) here but not on any other SE site; how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I can tell, you've only got one overall Stack Exchange account (as [seen here](http://stackexchange.com/users/c4e32f81-1105-43d7-bdba-559fe3fa113c?tab=accounts)). Some of your SE site accounts have different information (such as Open IDs, as you noticed) but that doesn't mean you have multiple accounts.

If you want the same info everywhere:

- Pick one site that has your information just the way you want it
- On that site, go to your user page.
- On your user page, click the "Accounts" tab.
- Scroll to the bottom, and click the button that says "Copy *<site name>* Profile to Related Accounts"
- Things should now work the way you expect them to.

So if you, for instance, like the way your account looks on `judaism.stackexchange.com`, [go here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/472/monica-cellio?tab=accounts), scroll down, and click.

If this doesn't work for you, just add a comment here describing what happened.

Comment: Checked things out, was ready to write an answer and found Dori beat me to it. :)  She wrote it better than I was going to anyways!

Comment: This doesn't seem to have changed anything.  judaism.SE shows two openIDs, Google (primary) and LiveJournal (secondary).  If I look in to boardgames.SE with Google it shows no responses and a rep of 101; if I log in using LJ it shows a response and a rep of 121.  (And the badges are different.)  In neither case does the profile page display any OpenID associations like it does on judaism.SE.  Both are beta sites, so I would have expected them to behave the same way.  So it's not like the 20 rep points are all that big a deal or anything, but I'd rather not have two identities running around.

Comment: Correction: apparently I was looking at the profile page while logged out.  Depending on how I log in, I see a profile with either the Google OpenID or the LJ one, but not both like on judaism.SE.  I'm willing to collapse everything on Google and forget about LJ if I can figure out how.

Comment: Thank you!  Much appreciated.